# 'Stop Further Rules From Processing' doesn't work as expected

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community, shopping-cart-price-rules

Basically I have 2 shopping cart rules and I only want one to be applied at any one time.

My first shopping cart rule is a discount code that gives you 10% discount on products in your cart that are in a certain category.
And my second is a little more complex as it gives you 100% discount on a product when a differnet product is added to your cart. For example, if you have a t-shirt and a hat in your cart, then you get the hat for free.

So at the moment when I have the t-shirt and hat in the cart at the same time, I get a discount of £6.00 (which is the price of the hat).
Then when I enter the coupon code, I get a further 10% off. So if my t-shirt was £10 and the hat was £6, The total to be paid would be £9.

I need it so that only one of these rules can be applied at any one time, I don't mind how it works, just as long as customers cannot take advantage of this issue.

I have heard that this is something to do with the priorities of the rules, but I have spent a few hours playing around with different settings but cannot get this to work.

I've attached some screenshots of my rule settings, hopefully they will give you a better idea of what's going on.

Thank you

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm having this exact problem still, did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. Rules are applied in priority low to high (0 -> 1000)
2. Stop further rules: YES means, process THIS rule and then stop.

So if I understand you correctly, you want only one rule processed, so either discount on the hat or on the shirt.

Give the 100% hat discount priority 100 and the shirt priority 200, at least the hat Stop further processing: **YES**

So if the hat rule is processed it is stopped.

The priorities 100 and 200 are to have space between to add more rules, 1 and 2 would work either.

Comment: The OPs initial post says that he already is set up in the exact way your answer describes it (or I did misread either one). The issue OP is having is that also he has both rules with different priorities (1 and 2 in his case) and `Stop Futher Rules From Processing` set to `YES` in both, still both rules get applied/processed. Some Magento quirk which I'm currently seeing as well in a 1.9 installation.

Comment: No his priorities are wrong. 100% discount 2, less has 1. But nonetheless, both has Stop processing on, so in either way, only one rule should be processed. No more ideas. Happy debugging, xdebug is your friend!

Comment: I know this is kind of a lame answer but if this is a bug-> Upgrade to the latest Magento. Magento 1  is not supported anymore.  If what Fabian says is true .. Well then you just need to change your priorities

Comment: Magento 1 is still in security maintenance for years. Beside that M2 has still lots of other problems, so updating MIGHT fix that, but brings other problems - and costs a huge amount of money. And with 2.4 you have to redo most of the work, because it breaks with backwards compatibility. I'm really happy I do not have to decide that.